# Transmitting SOAP messages over Named Pipes in WCF

Tags: wcf, qt, soap, ipc

I fear I may be displaying my ignorance with this question, but here goes...

I would like to use WCF to implement interprocess communication between a .NET app and a third-party app written in Qt. The Qt app has a plugin architecture that, if I choose to, can be used to bootstrap some .NET classes to handle WCF cleanly at both ends, but I'd rather keep the codebase native and therefore I'm thinking of ways to make sure that whatever I send down the wire with WCF, I can reassemble at the other end using classes available in Qt.

Qt has a SOAP message class, so I figured the preferable solution - and the one that's closest to the one we've hacked together already - is to send SOAP messages and pick them up off a QLocalSocket. Question is, is it possible to force WCF to encode messages as SOAP over a NetNamedPipeBinding, and if so, is it wise to do so?

I'm feeling rather wary at this point that my question might not make complete sense due to my shaky understanding of the technology involved. If this is the case, please take the time to explain why instead of just saying 'no'.

**edit #1:** I figure an update is warranted, as I've investigated some and should report my findings.

Firstly, I have found that Qt is a pig. The QtSoapMessage class I mentioned, it turns out, doesn't exist in the current version, and is available only as an after-market source package that you have to compile yourself. It took me many hours of googling to find out why this wasn't working. The Qt documentation is utterly dreadful, Qt Creator is counterintuitive in the extreme, and I've all but lost patience with it so haven't pursued this idea any further as yet. Furthermore, it isn't obvious how exactly I am to pass the socket data into the soap message constructor, which takes a QDomDocument, whereas the API for reading XML from a socket uses a QXmlStreamReader or somesuch. There doesn't seem to be any conversion between them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually have a different problem to the one you think you have.

WCF will by default exchange SOAP messages over the NetNamedPipeBinding.

**However**, the message exchange is layered over some Microsoft proprietary protocols for transaction flow, message framing and encoding, which means that if on the Qt side you pick up a byte stream directly from a QLocalSocket you will have a lot of work to do to implement these underlying protocols before you will be able to get at the SOAP infoset itself.

It is possible to configure the NetNamedPipe binding to remove some of these protocol layers, but not all of them - the framing protocol will always be there, for example.

You might like to read my blog for [a lot more detail on this](http://blogs.charteris.com/blogs/chrisdi/archive/2010/11/04/talking-to-wcf-over-named-pipes-1-the-framing-protocol.aspx).

Comment: Wow, OK. That's really good information, in that it shows me that SOAP exchange is vastly more complicated than I had anticipated. The class I had imagined using from Qt is [QtSoapMessage](http://doc.trolltech.com/solutions/qtsoap/qtsoapmessage.html), which presumably since SOAP is a standard, can seamlessly interpret? I'd have to do some elaborate experimentation. Many thanks for your time.

Comment: @Tom: You're welcome... especially if you cared to click the little voting up arrow and/or accept :-)